# Unable to upload file flutter: too many positional arguments 0 expected

Tags: flutter, dart, file-io, upload

```
  Future pickImage() async {
final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

setState(() {
  _imageFile = File(pickedFile.path);
});
```

}

Error is thrown on line File(pickedFile.path), can't compile

Answer (score 0):

The issue was on package, I realized my file had

```
import 'package:file/file.dart';
```

package and

```
import 'dart:io';
```

I commented out

```
// import 'package:file/file.dart';
```

and all is fine now.